# Azure load balancer with NAT rule hiding port for RDP

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-load-balancer, azure-ilb

I have internet facing Azure load balancer with public static IP (call it PIP) and I added a NAT rule - forward TCP port 12345 to local (subnet's IP) 10.2.2.2:3389 (VM that doesn't have public IP). And I'm trying to set NSG for subnet and VM's NIC.

subnet's NSG rules (all TCP):

- 100: Source PIP:* => 10.2.2.2:3389 (from load balancer IP to VM's local IP)
- 120: Source Internet:12345 => 10.1.2.4:3389

VM's NSG rules:

- 100: PIP:* => 10.2.2.2:3389

and here's the problem: if I use Network Watcher's IP flow verify and set local IP to 10.2.2.2:3389, Remote IP:[PIP:12345] I get green light. Same with setting both ports (local and remote) to 3389. But when I'm trying to Remote Desktop to that VM from outside I get a connection error!

I have no idea why. The VM is up and running, all good here.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your subnet NSG inbound rules like this:

```
120: Source Internet:12345 => 10.2.2.2:3389
```

You should allow public IP address (from outside) to access your Azure subnet.

Comment: I removed subnet NSG completely. And now Network Watcher shows that from any ExtIP:20009 the VM can be accessed (green light all the way) but in reality I can't connect. And I don't have any firewalls.

Comment: @alvipeo could you please show me some screenshot about your LB nat rules and vm NSG

Comment: @alvipeo if you remove all NSG, does RDP work for you?

Comment: @alvipeo Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: Quick thought have you double checked your windows firewall on your VM is open to 3389?